# Is there a penis-detection demo similar to face-detection?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Is there a script/tutorial/demo for penis-detection similar to [this one](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html) on face-detection?

This is a fairly serious question, as the future of Internet memes is at stake. Breast / nipple detection would be handy, too.

Comment: ---- giggle ----

Comment: Although controversial, I will treat this question as a serious one - at least for now...

Comment: Was this resolved after all?

Answer (score 6):

> **Is there a script / tutorial / demo for penis detection?**
>
> [...]
>
> Fairly serious quesion, future of internet memes is at stake

Yes, there is.

Common [Pattern Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition) techniques will be able to spot one even with what would be considered today "traditional" approach (i.e. without "Deep Learning").

There already is a sub-category of the subject with people working on "Adult Content Detection". [Here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=adult-content) are a few relevant publications.

[This](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6011977/) is an example for detecting child pornography which contains an overview and references to other techniques along with what the authors are proposing.

There is [an increasingly large amount of tutorials out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=build+your+own+image+classifier) on how to use a number of popular libraries to build an "Image Classifier", some of them not even requiring writing code. So, getting to a "script" that does what you are after is not a huge amount of work.

Hope this helps